# Multi dependent drop down list Excel

Tags: excel

I'm new to Excel so apologies if this is a simple task but I've been wrecking my head over it for a few days now, looking at videos and reading guides but none have really helped me with what I need to do.

I'm looking to create 3 drop down boxes, with the next drop down dependent on the previous.

[image]

So in G1 if I select Football, in G2 it should come up with a list of "La Liga, Premier League", and if I select "Premier League" then G3 should come up with "Liverpool vs Manchester United, Manchester City vs Wolverhampton Wanderers".

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be accomplished by creating an auxiliary/preparation table, which I have created in columns `I:K` (but can be in any other range).

First, repeat the headings of your main table in the range `I1:K1`. In cell `I2`, enter the following formula: `=UNIQUE(A2:A12)`; in cell `J2` the following formula: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(B2:B12, A2:A12=G1))`; and in cell `K2` the following formula: `=UNIQUE(FILTER(C2:C12, (A2:A12=G1) * (B2:B12=G2)))`.
These steps are used to create the unique list of observations that meet certain conditions, e.g., being a competition in a particular sport.

Now you need to set up your lists based on the dynamic ranges. For the first list, go to the cell `G2` -> tab `Data` -> `Data Validation` -> `Allow: List` -> `Source: =$I$2#`.

Repeat this process for the cells `G3` and `G4`, while changing the source to `=$J$2#` and `=$K$2#`, respectively.