# Require a dropdown list based on input that matches Column header

Tags: excel, excel-formula

Kindly help me out with this problem.

The input is supposed to be Heading 1 or Heading 2 or Heading 3 or Heading 4 or Heading 5

The output will be a dropdown list to select which matches the tale.

I tried using lookup but could not arrive at a suitable solution. I am not conversant with VBA codes.

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Multi dependent drop down list Excel](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73012554/multi-dependent-drop-down-list-excel)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obviously achieve this using a helper column in some where in the worksheet:

[image]

---

In Action:

[image]

---

• Place the below formula in cell `U2`

```
=FILTER(K2:K18,MMULT((L2:P18="✔")*(S2=L1:P1),SEQUENCE(COLUMNS(L1:P1),,1,0)))
```

---

• Now select the cell `S7` and hit <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>

• This opens the `Data Validation` window --> select **Allow:** `List` and in **Source:** write `=U2#`

• And Press **Ok**, you will get the desired output, you are looking for.

---

Note: For Tick Marks I have used **Font:** `Segoe UI Symbol` and **Subset:** `Dingbats` (**Character Code - 2714**).

[image]